# bad texture overlay on the model

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

I have a bad texture overlay on the object.

I created an object and made for it Smart UV Project, island Margin made 0.001, then in shade editor made such a scheme, on all three materials and of course created a new image Texture with Alpha channel.

Then clicked started to bake and eventually came out such a texture, I put it already in the engine and it ended up badly overlaid.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please pack your image (File >External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file (only the object): https://blend-exchange.com/